# SQL Server update statement performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have problem in optimizing an SQL query to do some data cleansing.

In fact, I have a table which is a sort of referential of a multiple special characters and word. Let's call it `ABNORMAL(ID,PATTERN)`

I have also another table `INDIVIDUALS` containing a column (`NAME`) which I want to clean by removing from it all characters that exist in the table `ABNORMAL`.

Currently, I have tried to use update statements, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this.

## Approach one

Use a while loop to build a replace containing all characters from `ABNORMALS` by a blank '' and do one update using the built-in `REPLACE`

```
DECLARE @REPLACE_EXPRESSION  nvarchar(max) ='REPLACE(NAME,'''','''')'
DECLARE @i int  = 1
DECLARE @nbr int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ABNORMAL) 
-- CURRENT_CHARAC
DECLARE @CURRENT_CHARAC nvarchar(max) 
-- NEW REPLACE EXPRESSION TO IMBRICATE INTO THE REPLACE EXPRESSION VARIABLE
DECLARE @CURR_REP NVARCHAR(max)
-- STRING TO BUILD AN SQL QUERY CONTAINING THE REPLACE EXPRESSION
DECLARE @UPDATE_QUERY nvarchar(max) 
WHILE @i < @nbr
BEGIN 
    SELECT @CURRENT_CHARAC=PATTERN FROM CLEANSING_STG_PRISM_FRA_REF_UNSIGNIFICANT_VALUES WHERE ID_PATTERN=@i ;
    SET @REPLACE_EXPRESSION = REPLACE(@REPLACE_EXPRESSION ,'NAME','REPLACE(NAME,'+''''+@CURRENT_CHARAC+''''+','''')')
    set @i=@i+1
END
SET @UPDATE_QUERY = 'UPDATE INDIVIDUAL  SET NAME ='+ @REPLACE_EXPRESSION
EXEC sp_executesql @UPDATE_QUERY
```

## Approach two

Use a while loop to select every character in abnormal and do an update using replace containing the characters to remove:

```
DECLARE @i int  = 1
DECLARE @nbr int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ABNORMAL) 
-- CURRENT_CHARAC
DECLARE @CURRENT_CHARAC nvarchar(max) 
-- STRING TO BUILD AN SQL QUERY CONTAINING THE REPLACE EXPRESSION
DECLARE @UPDATE_QUERY nvarchar(max) 
WHILE @i < @nbr
BEGIN 
    SELECT @CURRENT_CHARAC=PATTERN FROM CLEANSING_STG_PRISM_FRA_REF_UNSIGNIFICANT_VALUES WHERE ID_PATTERN=@i ;
    UPDATE INDIVIDUAL 
    SET NAME = REPLACE(NAME,@CURRENT_CHARAC,'')
    SET @i=@i+1
END
```

I already tested both approaches for 2 millions records, and I found that the first approach is faster than the second. I would know if you have already done something similar and new (better) ideas to try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SQL Server 2017` you could use [`TRANSLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql) and avoid dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT i.*
  , REPLACE(TRANSLATE(i.NAME, f, REPLICATE('!', s.l)), '!', '') AS cleansed
FROM INDIVIDUALS i
OUTER APPLY (SELECT STRING_AGG(PATTERN, '') AS f
                   ,LEN(STRING_AGG(PATTERN,'')) AS l
             FROM ABNORMAL) AS s
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=6e8eaa118d5e6dd76e9f47b1f3daaeee)**

---

Anyway 1st approach is better becasue you do one `UPDATE`, with second approach you remove characters one character at time (so you will have multiple `UPDATE`).

I would also track transaction log growth with both approaches.

Comment: Hello,thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately i'm using sql server 2016. But could you please clarify what did you mean by 'track transaction log' ? and how could this optimize my query ?

Answer (score 0):

If there's not too many characters that to be cleaned, then this trick might work.

Basically, you build 1 big update statement with a replace for each value in the table with the characters to be removed.

Example code:

**Test data (using temp tables)**

```
create table #ABNORMAL_CHARACTERS (id int identity(1,1), chr varchar(30));
insert into #ABNORMAL_CHARACTERS (chr) values ('!'),('&'),('#');

create table #INDIVIDUAL (id int identity(1,1), name varchar(30));
insert into #INDIVIDUAL (name) values ('test 1 &'),('test !&#2'),('test 3');
```

**Code:**

```
declare @FieldName varchar(30) = 'name';
declare @Replaces varchar(max) = @FieldName;
declare @UpdateSQL varchar(max);

select @Replaces = concat('replace('+@Replaces+', ', ''''+chr+''','''')') from #ABNORMAL_CHARACTERS order by id;

set @UpdateSQL = 'update #INDIVIDUAL 
set name = '+@Replaces + ' 
where exists (select 1 from #ABNORMAL_CHARACTERS where charindex(chr,name)>0)';

exec (@UpdateSQL);

select * from #INDIVIDUAL;
```

A test [here on rextester](http://rextester.com/NWKGX72122)

And if you would have a UDF that can do a regex replace. 
For example [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/)
Then the @Replaces variable could be simplified with only 1 RegexReplace function and a pattern.